# Compilation error after replacing app folder

Tags: angular

Created a demo project in angular 7 from ng new demo command, replaced the app folder by an app folder from another project but got compilation error. What might be the reason?

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: The error was module not found: error, can't resolve 'componentname' in 'compaonentpathuptoapp'

Comment: If you replace your src folder with another project`s src folder, your components will be different and obviously it wont compile.